# Crockford - Chapter 7 - parse_url

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
```

Why is the dot . in this part 
    [0-9.-A-Za-z]+
not escaped by a backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets (`[]`) specify a character class: matching a single character in the string between `[]`.

While inside a character class, only the `\` and `-` have special meaning (are *metacharacters*):

- backslash `\`: general escape character.
- hyphen `-`: character range.

  - Notice, though, it must be between chars to have special meaning:

    - `[0-9]` means any number between `0` and `9`, while in `[09-]`, `-` assumes the quality of an ordinary `-`, not a range.

That's why, inside `[]`, a `.` is just (will only match) a dot.

**Note:** It is also worth noticing that the char `]` must be escaped to be used inside a character class, such as `[a-z\]]`, otherwise it will close it as usual. Finally, using `^`, as in `[^a-z]`, designates a *negated character class*, that means any char that is not one of those (in the example, any char that is not `a...z`).

Comment: For completeness, `]` and `^` also do things.

Comment: Thank you, acdcjunior. "While inside a character class, only the / and - have special meaning (are metacharacters)". Btw, did you mean forward slash or back slash here?

Comment: I meant backslash, my bad, I fixed the typo. @DaveNewton, you are right, it is worth mentioning those chars. I added a note at the end of the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks again. Can I split a correct answer between two people here and if so how? :)

Comment: OK, never mind, the last one seems like a question for meta.stackoverflow.com and also it seems it's already answered.

Answer (score 1):

So it matches a dot.

Except under some circumstances (e.g., escaping the range hyphen when it's not the first character in the character class brackets) you don't need to escape special characters in a class.

You *may* escape the normal metacharacters inside character classes, but it's noisy and redundant.